# How to fix the error "Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\Users\aashok\.ssh\id_rsa"?

Tags: java, ssh

I am trying to download some files using ssh from a linux server using the code in java, i have a ssh config file which is causing this error,
the content of the config file is below:

```
Host *
 ProxyCommand "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" -H 
webproxyhttp_address:8080 %h %p
 IdentityFile "C:/Users/aashok/.ssh/id_rsa"
 TCPKeepAlive yes
 IdentitiesOnly yes

Host bitbucket.org
 User git
 Port 22
 Hostname bitbucket.org
```

please help. Thanks

Comment: And does the file `C:/Users/aashok/.ssh/id_rsa` start with a `"`, as mentioned in the error message? **Do not post the file**, it's your private key. Mine starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: No, mine also starts with -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Can you try removing the `"` from the `IdentityFile` argument? Seems like `IdentityFile C:/Users/aashok/.ssh/id_rsa` might be enough?